# How to I can publish a package to Bower

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have just complete a package js, and now I try published it to Bower but it failed. I got a message:

```
bower angularjs-list-view#*    resolve https://github.com/ch91/angularjs-list-view.git#*
bower angularjs-list-view#*   download https://github.com/ch91/angularjs-list-view/archive/master.tar.gz
bower angularjs-list-view#*    extract archive.tar.gz
bower angularjs-list-view#*   resolved https://github.com/ch91/angularjs-list-view.git#2133de0024
? Registering a package will make it installable via the registry (https://registry.bower.io), continue? Yes
bower angularjs-list-view     register https://github.com/ch91/angularjs-list-view.git
bower                         EUNKNOWN Unknown error: 500 - Registering bower package names is not supported anymore. You can install any bower package on github with command like "bower install jquery/jquery-dist --save"
```

If I want still publish my package to Bower, so how I do it?
I need the package to resolve an issue for my Angularjs project.